# Change image width and height with screen rotation

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please, tell me how to change image width and height with orientation change using javascript. Unfrotunately, my code doesn`t work, here it is:

```
<script>window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function screenrotation() {
      var firstresposniverowphoto = document.getElementById("#firstresposniverowphoto");
      var secondresposniverowphoto = document.getElementById("#secondresposniverowphoto");
      if(screen.orientation=="portrait"){
          firstresposniverowphoto.width = '100%';
          secondresposniverowphoto.width = '100%';
      }if(screen.orientation=="landscape"){
          firstresposniverowphoto.width = '40vw';
          secondresposniverowphoto.width = '40vw';
      }                  
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers! I know that I did a very silly thing asking for JavaScript solution to the problem described by me previously. Instead I`ve realised that it is better to use CSS rather that JavaScript. Here is my solution:

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {

.contentOne{
box-shadow: 0 1vw 3vw 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
transition: 0.3s;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover; 
height:40vh;
width:40vw;
}
.contentOne:hover{
box-shadow: 0 2vw 4vw 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {

.contentOne{
box-shadow: 0 1vw 3vw 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
transition: 0.3s;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover; 
width:100%;
height:40vh;
margin:auto;
}
.contentOne:hover{
box-shadow: 0 2vw 4vw 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function detectmob() {
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}}if (detectmob()) {
    $(window).on("orientationchange", reloadIframe);
} else {
    $(window).on("resize", reloadIframe);
}
```

You can use the above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this **JQuery** and just have two separate images for two different orientations (landscape / portrait).

```
$(window).resize( function(){
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();

if(width>height) {
  // Landscape
  $("#img").attr("src","landscapeurl");
} else {
  // Portrait
  $("#img").attr("src","portraiturl");
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!